# Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, rufus

I am in the process to install Ubuntu on a brand-new Dell Windows 10 desktop. When I tried to boot on a bootable Ubuntu Bionic USB stick created by Rufus, I got a bug:

"Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed".

The partition style on my machine is GPT, and the bootable Ubuntu flash drive is in UEFI mode and GPT format. May I ask how to fix it? Thank you!

I have also created the bootable Ubuntu USB stick by UNetbootin and Universal USB Installer respectively, and booting on the USB stick does work either: I get the same error message, or the bootable Ubuntu flash drive does not even show up on the Boot Menu.

Comment: This sounds like a Ubuntu Groovy 20.10 problem. If so see bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1886148 20.10 is still off topic on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey ML6634! Did you verify your Ubuntu download? If no, do so by following the instructions here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu

Comment: Thank C.S.Cameron and technastic_tc for the comments! My computer is Alienware. Unfortunately, I do not think that Ubuntu is supported in Alienware computers.

Comment: Anyone has ever installed Ubuntu to a Dell computer, or even an Alienware computer? Thanks.